# XML Serialization of arrays

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, xml, serialization

I have the following xml file

```
<record>
    <patient>...</patient>
    <appointment>...</appointment>
    <appointment>...</appointment>
    <appointment>...</appointment>
    <prescription>...</prescription>
    <prescription>...</prescription>
    <prescription>...</prescription>
    <labresult>...</labresult>
    <labresult>...</labresult>
    <labresult>...</labresult>
</record>
```

patient is an object
appointment is an array of objects
prescription is an array of objects
labresult is an array of objects

I don't have control over the xml file as it is an export file.
When I deserialize it only processes the first xml element type I end up with 
appoinment, prescription, labresults being null. When I cut patient from the xml file I end up with an array of appointments (which is good) however prescription, labresult are null

I am using c# with the .net 4.5 framework.

Comment: Process it how into what??

Comment: Serialize the xml into c# objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could process the data using XDocument:

```
var xml = "<record>" +
      "  <patient></patient>" +
      "  <appointment></appointment>" +
      "  <appointment></appointment>" +
      "  <appointment></appointment>" +
      "  <prescription></prescription>" +
      "  <prescription></prescription>" +
      "  <prescription></prescription>" +
      "  <labresult></labresult>" +
      "  <labresult></labresult>" +
      "  <labresult></labresult>" +
      "</record>";
using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
    foreach (var xElement in xDoc.Root.Elements("patient")) {
        // Process patients
    }
    foreach (var xElement in xDoc.Root.Elements("appointment")) {
        // Process appointment
    }
    ...
}
```